# unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Tags: javascript, php, html, syntax-error

error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\html\updatedtimeline.html on line 109

Im getting this error in my code and i would like to understand why?
Thanks for any help

i want to add the email of the user logged in my html element

```
<h6 id="myemail">  </h6>
```

line 109:

```
echo "<script> document.getelementById('myemail').value= $_SESSION['email'] </script>";
```

Comment: Did you start the session before the scripting

Comment: `{$_SESSION['email']}` <-- note the braces. you may actually need `'{$_SESSION['email']}'` also the quotes

Comment: @PranavMS Yes i did

Comment: @MrTux Tried the following link and solution couldn't help me

Comment: Value=".$_session['email']." Try this way

Comment: @PranavMS This solved my error but the value of the html element with id myemail isnt changing and this is the relative line:
`<h6 id="myemail">  </h6>`

Comment: Good  ..  before asking questions just debug your code.

Comment: have you checked my comment? you need quotes also.

Comment: @bansi Yes I've changed my line to `echo "<script> document.getelementById('myemail').value= '{$_SESSION['email']}' </script>";` am i following right? if yes then i'm getting the same problem the html element isn't changing accordingly

Comment: yes that is correct. Check what is the value in `$_SESSION['email']` and re-check if your element has id `myemail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
<?php session_start();?>

    <h6 id="myemail">  </h6>

    <?php
        echo "<script> document.getElementById('myemail').innerHTML = '{$_SESSION['email']}'; </script>";
    ?>
```

Please make sure that your `echo` should be placed after `<h6 id="myemail">  </h6>` is printed out.

**Please pay attention to the order of the code.
You should make sure `<h6 id="myemail">  </h6>` is printed already before you `echo` script code.**

Comment: I've made this changes and im getting a debug error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`

Comment: then your `$_SESSION['email']` is not set

Comment: @menna `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null` should be happening in javascript console, correct? I have updated the code. Check it out.

Comment: @bansi To check the value of my ` $_SESSION['email']` i tried `echo "welcome " . $_SESSION['email'];` and i got `welcome iahmedwael@gmail.com` (Which shows that my value of session is correct) and my html element has an id myemail as the following `<h6 id="myemail"> </h6>`

Comment: @RayC my code was changed accordingly to `<?php

session_start();    

echo "<script> document.getElementById('myemail').innerHTML = '{$_SESSION['email']}'; </script>";
    
?>` and im getting a debug error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

Comment: @menna As I mentioned in my answer, please make sure you have `<h6 id="myemail">  </h6>` already printed before you do `echo` thing. My suggestion is, you move `echo` thing to the last part of your code, so that make `<h6 id="myemail">  </h6>` is already printed.